# AdaptiveCard native method on android not found

Tags: android, adaptive-cards

i'm tring to launch the basic adaptive card example using maven central depencdency but i'm having an error because native method impl is not being found.

I have just add the dependency to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'io.adaptivecards:adaptivecards-android-arm:1.0.0'
```

This is the error:

```
11-13 18:19:55.944 16684-16970 E/zygote: No implementation found for long com.microsoft.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI.AdaptiveCard_DeserializeFromString(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_microsoft_adaptivecards_objectmodel_AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI_AdaptiveCard_1DeserializeFromString and Java_com_microsoft_adaptivecards_objectmodel_AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI_AdaptiveCard_1DeserializeFromString__Ljava_lang_String_2)
11-13 18:19:55.945 16684-16684 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-13 18:19:55.949 16684-16684 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.tuenti.messenger, PID: 16684
                                                 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.microsoft.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI.AdaptiveCard_DeserializeFromString(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_microsoft_adaptivecards_objectmodel_AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI_AdaptiveCard_1DeserializeFromString and Java_com_microsoft_adaptivecards_objectmodel_AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI_AdaptiveCard_1DeserializeFromString__Ljava_lang_String_2)
                                                     at com.microsoft.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI.AdaptiveCard_DeserializeFromString(Native Method)
                                                     at com.microsoft.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString(AdaptiveCard.java:105)
```

I have checked the generated APK and it contains the SO for adaptive cards but still does not work.

Comment: Can you try adding a static ctor before accessing the API and see if that helps? 
`static { System.loadLibrary("adaptivecards-native-lib"); }`

https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/android/mobile/src/main/java/com/microsoft/adaptivecards/adaptivecardssample/MainActivityAdaptiveCardsSample.java#L45-L47

Comment: Yes, was that. Post an answer and i accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a static ctor before accessing the API and see if that helps.

```
static { 
    System.loadLibrary("adaptivecards-native-lib"); 
}
```